# MARIE is not displaying the correct sum in the output window

Tags: assembly, marie

I am currently working in the MARIE simulator, and I'm trying to edit the assembly code so that, although it still loops through the six given numbers for addition purposes (15, 25, 20, 30, 35, 10), it checks which of them are smaller than 22, and adds those together while ignoring all numbers > 22.  It then needs to display the result in the "output" window of the MARIE simulator

Here is the code I started with:

```
        Load     Addr   /Load address of first number to be added       
        Store    Next   /Store this address is our Next pointer     
        Load     Num    /Load the number of items to be added       
        Subt     One    /Decrement      
        Store    Ctr    /Store this value in Ctr to control looping     
Loop,   Load     Sum    /Load the Sum into AC       
        AddI     Next   /Add the value pointed to by location Next      
        Store    Sum    /Store this sum 
        Output  
        Load     Next   /Load Next      
        Add      One    /Increment by one to point to next address      
        Store    Next   /Store in our pointer Next      
        Load     Ctr    /Load the loop control variable     
        Subt     One    /Subtract one from the loop control variable        
        Store    Ctr    /Store this new value in loop control variable      
        Skipcond 000    /If control variable < 0, skip next instruction     
        Jump     Loop   /Otherwise, go to Loop  
        Halt            /Terminate program      
Addr,   Hex      118    /Numbers to be summed start at location 118     
Next,   Hex      0      /A pointer to the next number to add        
Num,    Dec      6      /The number of values to add        
Sum,    Dec      0      /The sum        
Ctr,    Hex      0      /The loop control variable      
One,    Dec      1      /Used to increment and decrement by 1       
        Dec      15     /The values to be added together        
        Dec      25
        Dec      20
        Dec      30
        Dec      35 
        Dec      10
```

This is the code I've modified somewhat; however, all it does is return a list of "5"s instead of the addition of the numbers I need:

```
        Load     Addr   /Load address of first number to be added       
        Store    Next   /Store this address is our Next pointer     
        Load     Num    /Load the number of items to be added       
        Subt     One    /Decrement      
        Store    Ctr    /Store this value in Ctr to control looping 
Loop,   Load     Sum    /Load the Sum into AC   
        Subt     124    /subtracts the value at 124 (22)    
        Skipcond 800    /if > 22, skip the next instruction 
        AddI     Next   /Add the value pointed to by location Next      
        Store    Sum    /Store this sum 
        Output  
        Load     Next   /Load Next      
        Add      One    /Increment by one to point to next address      
        Store    Next   /Store in our pointer Next      
        Load     Ctr    /Load the loop control variable     
        Subt     One    /Subtract one from the loop control variable        
        Store    Ctr    /Store this new value in loop control variable      
        Skipcond 000    /If control variable < 0, skip next instruction     
        Jump     Loop   /Otherwise, go to Loop  
        Halt            /Terminate program      
Addr,   Hex      118    /Numbers to be summed start at location 118     
Next,   Hex      0      /A pointer to the next number to add        
Num,    Dec      6      /The number of values to add        
Sum,    Dec      0      /The sum        
Ctr,    Hex      0      /The loop control variable      
One,    Dec      1      /Used to increment and decrement by 1       
        Dec      15     /The values to be added together        
        Dec      25
        Dec      20
        Dec      30
        Dec      35 
        Dec      10 
        Dec      22
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the Skipcond to make it put out

[image]

Comment: Why not show us how you got 124 == 22.

Comment: 124 is the memory address of the variable 22.  From my understanding, assembly uses the memory address to report what's stored at that location.  if I put 22 in there, it would seek out the value stored at memory address 22.

Comment: you added code but didn't fix up the addresses